# CMYK value for #BA00FF?

Tags: color, cmyk, rgb, color-match

A friend handed me a logo file with an RGB color of #BA00FF. I'm having trouble finding an exact CMYK match for the bright purple color.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You wont get it the same, as rgb and cmyk are different colour spaces and represent different parts of the visible spectrum. The closest you'll get is 27% cyan, 100% magenta, 0% yellow, 0% black, according to the website colorhexa

Comment: Yes but what color profile is that color in FOGRA?